# Using will in interrogatives?

Tags: sentence-construction, past-tense, conditional-constructions, past-perfect, will-would

I really find it difficult to frame a proper English sentence.

I want to ask if this sentence is correct or not:

> will she be happy if she **comes** to know that you bought it from the stolen money?

In this sentence alright?

Do I have to use bought or have bought or had bought?

Do I need to replace *comes* by *will come* or something else ?

Answer (score 1):

The sentence is grammatically correct as written, but the phrase "comes to know" is rather unusual and very formal. I suggest "learns" or "finds out" for a more conversational feel.

Comment: Curious about downvotes on the answer. Any constructive feedback on the answer or the question?

Comment: Do you find that "will" is okay in the question? I think "would" would be more suitable as the asker is not sure of her reaction. I mean the question is mainly about this issue but you didn't comment on it.

Answer (score 0):

The sentence:

> Will she be happy if she comes to know that you bought it from the stolen money?

is grammatically correct as it stands.

- While "would" might be used in place of will, I think "will" is better. This is not discussing an unreal past, or a surely false or highly improbable future, but a plausible but uncertain future.
- "bought" should **not** be replaced by "have bought" or "had bought", the buying is in the past, and there is no reason to use anything but the simple past here.
- The word "comes" should not be replaced by "will come", that would be used for a nearly certain future development "She will come to know her real self".
- However, as the answer by Valkor correctly indicates, "will come to know" is rather formal, indeed I would call it old-fashioned. "if she learns", "if she finds out", "if she gets to know", or "if she becomes aware" would all be more natural, with the latter two more formal than the first two.